# Rails thinks my join table has different column names

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between photos and albums in a Rails app. My join table looks like this in the MySQL database:

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| photoID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| albumID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

However, when I go into the rails console and query:

```
photo = Photo.find(1)
photo.albums
```

I get an `Unknown column 'albums_photos.photo_id' in 'where clause'` error because of the generated MySQL query, which was:

```
SELECT `albums`.*
FROM `albums`
INNER JOIN `albums_photos`
ON `albums`.`albumID` = `albums_photos`.`album_id` 
WHERE `albums_photos`.`photo_id` = 1
```

As you can see from the database, the keys are not `album_id` and `photo_id` , but are actually `albumID` and `photoID`. Where should I look first to find the cause of this problem? Here are my models for the three.

**Album:**

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
end
```

**Photo:**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
end
```

**AlbumPhoto:**

```
class AlbumPhoto < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :photo
    belongs_to :album
end
```

(Note: I imported this database directly into MySQL from a .sql file, not via a migration, if that information helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :photos, :association_foreign_key => 'photoID'
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :albums, :association_foreign_key => 'albumID'
end
```

**EDIT**

Does your migration looks like this:

```
create_table :albums_photos do |t|
  t.integer :album_id
  t.integer :photo_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Added this. Same error as before. Do I need to compile something/do something more after adding this before trying it in the rails console again?

Comment: Should I change my AlbumPhoto to what I had before?

Comment: Yeah revert that and try

Comment: With the new code you posted, and my old AlbumPhoto, I'm still getting the same error (It's still trying to query with photo_id and album_id

Comment: Using `grep -r "photo_id" .` i'm not finding any occurrences of `photo_id` other than in the ./log/development.log file

Comment: SELECT `albums`.* FROM `albums` INNER JOIN `albums_photos` ON `albums`.`albumID` = `albums_photos`.`photoID` WHERE `albums_photos`.`photo_id` = 1

Comment: ^ That's the query it's creating now

Comment: Ok try appending `:join_table => "albums_photos"` after `association foreign key`

Comment: I instead tried dropping the albums_photos table and having one generated using migration, and now the generated table only has albumID as a foreign key :(

Comment: Ok, check if your migration looks like the migaration I posted in the answer

Comment: It doesn't look like that.

Comment: Can you post your migration? I hope if you change your migration to what I posted, it must fix your problem